# Extract each digit of variable and store as new variable in bash

Tags: bash

I have a variable that is a number ranging from 1 - infinity. Lets say the number is 40.  I need to store 4 as a variable, and 0 as a variable.  Since the number can grow beyond 2 digits, lets say the number is 125.  I need to store 1 as a variable, 2 as a variable, and 5 as a variable.
How can I do this with bash?

Comment: Is also an array possible?

Comment: @Cyrys - Absolutely.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a counting loop over the length of the value you want to split to digits, and put the digits into an array, for example:

```
value=125
arr=()
for ((i = 0; i < ${#value}; i++)); do
    arr+=(${value:$i:1})
done

for x in "${arr[@]}"; do
    echo $x
done
```

This will print:

> ```
> 1
> 2
> 5
> ```